# change Url.Action(Action,Controller) default functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, aspnetboilerplate

I don't know what is wrong with my routing configuration.

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

but `@Url.Action("Index","Agent")` returns

> http://localhost:61759/agent

rather than

> http://localhost:61759/Agent/Index

Please let me know what is missing :)

P.S
I don't want to disturb the default routing settings i.e

1. http://localhost:61759 should route to default page
2. http://localhost:61759/Agent should route to http://localhost:61759/Agent/Index

Answer (score 0):

Map a route without `action = "Index"` **before** the "Default" route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "NoDefaultAction",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

// Code below unchanged
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Now `@Url.Action("Index", "Agent")` returns `"/Agent/Index"` and "Default" route is undisturbed:

> 1. http://localhost:61759 should route to default page
> 2. http://localhost:61759/Agent should route to http://localhost:61759/Agent/Index